# Classic ASP - How to return value of specific line in a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql, asp-classic

I have a Table named "LANGUAGE" - with words in SPANISH and ENGLISH.

Like:

```
ID - SPA - ENG
1 - Hoy - Hello
2 - Nombre - Name
3 - Jugar - Play
```

I Got the Spanish words:

```
SQL= "SELECT SPA FROM LANGUAGES" 
SET LANGDB = conn.Execute(SQL)
```

And I want to identify ID 2 word (Nombre) to print on screen

It's possible? Or I need to create a DB for each word?

like:

```
SQL= "SELECT SPA FROM LANGUAGES WHERE ID = 2" 
SET LANGDB = conn.Execute(SQL)
```

Tks!

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem with the SQL you have?

Comment: Hi @Tomalak - The SQL are good. My doubt is if we have a better solution to get each line of the table because if I have in the page 200 words to get I will need to create 200 Set DBs. I need something like: LANGDB("ID 1") for ID 1... LANGDB("ID 2") for ID 2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're trying to retrieve the Spanish word for a given English word:

```
SELECT SPA FROM LANGUAGES WHERE ENG = 'Name"
```

This will return 'Nobre'

If you're wanting to return both words for all of the rows:

```
SELECT SPA, ENG FROM LANGUAGES
```

Comment: Hi @Troy-Turley! Tks for your time! yes, but my problem is - if I have to know 200 words I will need to create 200 Selects? we don't have a better solution to get each word with one only select?

Comment: I updated the answer. This will return all of the words in one recordset. Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

So you are worried that querying the database many times for tiny words will cause slowdown. Yes, that could be an issue. Sending many queries to the database will definitely introduce overhead.

What you could do:

- create an [ASP application](https://www.sitepoint.com/asp-sessions-applications/) in IIS (if you haven't already),
- write a `global.asa` file,
- add a an `Application_OnStart` Sub (this runs exactly once, when your ASP application starts)
- inside, send a single SQL query to the DB that returns all language variables
- write a `While Not rs.EOF` loop (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19993024/18771)) that adds all of them as application-level variables
- use a clean naming scheme inside the loop, like `Application("lang_SPA_" & rs!ID) = rs!SPA` and so on.

Now all your language variables are available immediately across your application, since you can access the `Application` object anywhere. For example, `Application("lang_SPA_2")` would contain `"Nombre"`.

Be aware that `Application_OnStart` only runs once, so when you make changes to the database, you need to restart the application in IIS (this is done by stopping and starting the Application Pool that you have assigned to your application).

Comment: hi @tomalak!, First of all, tks for share your time! Yes, you understand my issue. I'm worried about this. I Will try here and feedback you asap. tks a loooot!

Answer (score 0):

How about creating `config.asp` file. First save the language selection value in database as 0 or 1. Then inside of `config.asp` file write the condition like -

```
if lang = 0 then 'eng
  Session("ID_1") = "Hello"
  Session("ID_2") = "Name"
elseif lang = 1 then 'spanish
  Session("ID_1") = "Hoy"
  Session("ID_2") = "Nombre"
end if
```

Now, you can use these sessions.

Comment: hi @Kiran, thanks for your time to help me! hum... good idea, I'm not an expert - but I have 200 words (with some long texts). Session can store all this? Or I have a limit to create sessions?

Comment: Yeah, you can have as many sessions as you want with long texts.